# How to type a React.Children.map with additional props that are not exposed to the consumer of the component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

(For simplicity, I threw a few any's here and there)

On the consumer side, I got -

```js
const Foo: React.FunctionComponent<{
  items: Array<{ id: string; title: string; caption: string }>;
}> = ({ items }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<number | null>(null);
  const handleChange = (_: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number | null) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper value={value} handleChange={handleChange}>
      {items.map(({ id, title, caption }) => {
        return <Inner key={id} title={title} caption={caption} />;
      })}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

What Wrapper does is takes the children and passes them some extra props, like so -

```js
const Wrapper: React.FunctionComponent<{
  value: number | null;
  handleChange: any;
}> = ({ value, handleChange, children }) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
    if (!child || !React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return null;
    }
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      onChange: handleChange(index),
      value,
      selected: value === index,
      ...child.props,
    });
  });
};
```

And eventually, Inner is -

```js
const Inner: React.FunctionComponent<{
  title: string;
  caption: string;
  onChange: any;
  value: number | null;
  selected: boolean;
}> = ({ title, caption, onChange, value, selected }) => {
  return (
    <ThirdPartyComponent onChange={onChange} value={value} selected={selected}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <h5>{caption}</h5>
    </ThirdPartyComponent>
  );
};
```

The issue is that Inner's interface requires things that are not passed in Foo but are passed in Wrapper.
I'm trying to find a way to type it in a way that will not expose these props to the consumer.
Setting these props as optional is a solution I don't like because it exposes them to the consumer.
So far, I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the props is not explicit, hence the problem.
If `Wrapper` is used only for this logic I would rewrite it into a hook and there return the missing props:

```
const wrapperProps = useWrapper(value, handleChange)
return (
  <>
    {items.map(({ id, title, caption }, index) => {
      return <Inner key={id} title={title} caption={caption} {...wrapperProps(index)} />;
    })}
  </>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the idea, but I'm trying to keep the structure as is and find a way to properly type it.

Comment: If so, you can simply pass these items into the Wrapper component via prop, and there run the map. Besides that, I can't see any other option.

Comment: The Foo component doesn't know what is going on with children in the Wrapper component, so I don't think is there any other option to type it properly in this case.